# dhtmlx gantt Asynchronous loading data

Tags: dhtmlx

I want to set the + sign on the first level directory in the left tree of dhtmlx Gantt to be fixed. All children data are loaded asynchronously;

Here are two questions

1. How to set the icon of the first level directory? And the icon is a variable, dynamic setting;
2. If the click event is triggered when the icon is clicked to record the children data asynchronously;

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the `gantt.config.branch_loading` property if you use the `gantt.load` function to load tasks:

https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_branch_loading_config.html

Here are examples of how it works:

https://snippet.dhtmlx.com/5/0a810c38b

https://snippet.dhtmlx.com/5/7098d7c4d

There is no same functionality for the `gantt.parse` method. You need to manually implement a custom solution. To add the expand button ("+") to a task, you need to add the `$has_child` property to the task object.
In the following snippet, you can see how it works:

http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/253d73f85